# How can I use an object as a basis for a react component's state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to have two components use the same instance of a class to share state between them.

The background of my use case is that I want to keep the business logic entirely in my classes, including methods to display them on the UI.

The project is built using react-script.

From my understanding of the useRef- and useEffect-Hooks, I would have expected the following to work:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

class myClassImpl {
  constructor() {
    this.count = 0;
  }
  click = () => {
    this.count++;
    console.log(this.count);
  };
}

function App() {
  const myClass = new myClassImpl();
  return (
    <>
      <SomeStatefulComponent property={myClass}></SomeStatefulComponent>
      <SomeButton property={myClass}></SomeButton>
    </>
  );
}

function SomeStatefulComponent({ property }) {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(property.count);
  // create a reference to the mutable count 
  const ref = useRef(property.count);
  // update the state when ref changes, which should be when count changes
  useEffect(() => setCount(ref.current), [ref]);
  return <p>{count}</p>;
}

function SomeButton({ property }) {
  return <button onClick={property.click}>increment</button>;
}

export default App;
```

However, it does not, but the console.log statement in the function click() shows that the count member is updated.

I also tried with the following:

```
function SomeStatefulComponent({ property }) {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(property.count);
  useEffect(() => {
    setCount(property.count);
  }, [property.count]);
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{count}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

It doesn't work, either.

The following does work:

```
class myClassImpl {
  constructor() {
    this.count = 0;
  }
  click = () => {
    this.count++;
    console.log(this.count);
    this.setCount(this.count);
  };
  setHandler = (setCount) => {
    this.setCount = setCount;
  };
}


function SomeStatefulComponent({ property }) {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(property.count);
  useEffect(() => {
    property.setHandler(setCount);
  }, [property]);
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{count}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

However, implementing an observer pattern like this myself does not seem to me to be a very react- or js-way of solving this.

I assume that I'm not getting some very basic point. Please enlighten me :)

Comment: No, `ref`s don't create any sort of observable, they're just "boxes" for objects. Component updates are driven solely by prop or state changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just if somebody is going to stumble about this, I want to document how I actually solved it:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

class myClassImpl {
  constructor() {
    this.count = 0;
    this.observers = [];
  }
  click = () => {
    this.count++;
    this.observers.forEach((f) => f({ ...this }));
  };
  subscribe = (setState) => {
    if (this.observers.indexOf(setState) === -1) {
      this.observers.push(setState);
    }
  };
  unsubscribe = (setState) => {
    this.observers = this.observers.filter((f) => {
      return f !== setState;
    });
  };
}

function App() {
  const myClass = new myClassImpl();
  return (
    <>
      <SomeStatefulComponent myClass={myClass}></SomeStatefulComponent>
      <SomeButton myClass={myClass}></SomeButton>
    </>
  );
}

function SomeStatefulComponent({ myClass }) {
  const [state, setState] = useState({ ...myClass });
  useEffect(() => {
    myClass.subscribe(setState);
    return function cleanup() {
      myClass.unsubscribe(setState);
    };
  }, [myClass]);
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{state.count}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

function SomeButton({ myClass }) {
  return <button onClick={myClass.click}>increment</button>;
}
export default App;
```

*What does it do?*

- it leaves the state of the component completely in the object. In the useEffect, the component subscribes its `setState` method to the object; methods changing the state of the class need to inform all interested components. This leaves the decision whether or not state should be updated to the class.
- The component could also just declare a few of the components as state using deconstruction, since the spread operator handles copying. Like this `const [{ count }, setState] = useState({ ...myClass });`. 
   This will stop the component from re-rendering when its state hasn't actually changed
- The useEffect returns a 'cleanUp' function which is called by react on unmounting the component. The cleanUp function unsubscribes from the object, removing a potential memory leak.
- however, the components are tightly coupled to the objects and need to access their fields directly, getters don't work. Using methods to access the fields does work, though (beware the spread-syntax: the methods must be declared as functions bound to the instance like `getProp = ()=>{return this.prop}`). However, this means that the component will re-render every time the class informs the subscribers, regardless of value changes.
- one can, however, use a custom observer instead of the setState method to solve that issue. The following will only trigger a re-render if a value changes that is of actual interest and decouples the component from the fields of the class.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const observe = (o) => {
      if (o.getCount() !== state.count) {
        setState({ ...state, count: o.getCount() });
      }
    };
    myClass.subscribe(observe);
    return function cleanup() {
      myClass.unsubscribe(observe);
    };
  }, [myClass, state]);
```

- I have decided on that implementation to keep everything where it belongs. The classes know how to display themselves and keep their state local; objects will send each other messages, including something like 'please display yourself here in my UI when the user clicks my 'show details' button. This design approach means that changes are highly localized.
- The drawback is that this is a bit verbose.

I'm grateful for feedback :)

Answer (score 0):

Let's keep it simple, you just need to share state between components, no needs to create another class

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  return (
    <>
      <SomeStatefulComponent count={count}></SomeStatefulComponent>
      <SomeButton increment={() => setCount(count + 1)}></SomeButton>
    </>
  );
}

function SomeStatefulComponent({ count }) {
  return <p>{count}</p>;
}

function SomeButton({ increment }) {
  return <button onClick={increment}>increment</button>;
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I see how this would work, but that's not fulfilling my usecase:
_The background of my use case is that I want to keep the business logic entirely in my classes, including methods to display them on the UI._

Comment: Why not using redux? You will have centralized state and methods that update it, and you will be able access it anywhere within the context

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I assume redux is a library? I've not yet used it, I'm a bit new to all of this (it's a side project). Do I assume correctly that I would put all my objects into some redux 'container'?

Comment: You will make a store that will be a "single source of truth", from where you will dispatch actions and distribute states across your application. It's very common to use redux for state management, or if you're familiar with reducer and context hooks, it's basically the same pattern but redux has a cleaner approach, although a bit verbose